# HDFS File Checksum

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, checksum

I am trying to check the consistency of a file after copying to HDFS using Hadoop API - DFSCleint.getFileChecksum().

I am getting the following output for the above code:

```
Null
HDFS : null
Local : null
```

Can anyone point out the error or mistake?
Here is the Code :

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileChecksum;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;


public class fileCheckSum {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

         FileSystem hadoopFS = FileSystem.get(conf);
    //  Path hdfsPath = new Path("/derby.log");

        LocalFileSystem localFS = LocalFileSystem.getLocal(conf);
    //      Path localPath = new Path("file:///home/ubuntu/derby.log");


    //  System.out.println("HDFS PATH : "+hdfsPath.getName());
    //      System.out.println("Local PATH : "+localPath.getName());

        FileChecksum hdfsChecksum = hadoopFS.getFileChecksum(new Path("/derby.log"));
        FileChecksum localChecksum = localFS.getFileChecksum(new Path("file:///home/ubuntu/derby.log"));


        if(null!=hdfsChecksum || null!=localChecksum){
            System.out.println("HDFS Checksum : "+hdfsChecksum.toString()+"\t"+hdfsChecksum.getLength());
            System.out.println("Local Checksum : "+localChecksum.toString()+"\t"+localChecksum.getLength());

            if(hdfsChecksum.toString().equals(localChecksum.toString())){
                System.out.println("Equal");
            }else{
                System.out.println("UnEqual");

            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Null");
            System.out.println("HDFS : "+hdfsChecksum);
            System.out.println("Local : "+localChecksum);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: why checksum for HDFS file is NULL?

Comment: is there any other way(s) to compute MD5 Checksum for file on HDFS (i am using hadoop 0.20 , CDH3u3).

Also, can anyone suggest same function for CDH4.1 (MRv1).

Answer (score 11):

Since you aren't setting a remote address on the `conf` and essentially using the same configuration, both `hadoopFS` and `localFS` are pointing to an instance of `LocalFileSystem`.

`getFileChecksum` isn't implemented for `LocalFileSystem` and returns null. It should be working for `DistributedFileSystem` though, which if your `conf` is pointing to a distributed cluster, `FileSystem.get(conf)` should return an instance of `DistributedFileSystem` that returns an [MD5 of MD5 of CRC32 checksums](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3981) of chunks of size `bytes.per.checksum`. This value depends on the block size and the cluster-wide config, `bytes.per.checksum`. That's why these two params are also encoded in the return value of the distributed checksum as the name of the algorithm: MD5-of-xxxMD5-of-yyyCRC32 where xxx is number of CRC checksums per block and yyy is the `bytes.per.checksum` parameter.

The `getFileChecksum` isn't designed to be comparable across filesystems. Although it's possible to simulate the distributed checksum locally, or hand-craft map-reduce jobs to calculate equivalents of local hashes, I suggest relying Hadoop's own integrity checks that happens when a files gets written to or read from Hadoop

Comment: thanks for reply.
I got this point while debugging. I saw that my Configuration object was not reading hadoop conf files.

Now I am adding conf files explicitly and calculating md5sum for local file from unix shell and md5 for hdfs from java program.

But both the values are different for same file.

Comment: I am adding my conf file as 
conf.addResource(new Path("/home/ubuntu/CDH3/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u3/conf/core-site.xml"));
     conf.addResource(new Path("/home/ubuntu/CDH3/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u3/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

Comment: is DFSClient.getFileChecksum is different from what i am using?If yes, then how can i use this method.

I looked at hadoop src and found that this method is overloaded but i am unable to use this with one argument(String src).

Comment: It's MD5 of MD5 of CRC32 of the file. Implemented here: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/src/hdfs/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSClient.java#L570

Comment: what could be the value of  ClientProtocol namenode, SocketFactory socketFactory, int socketTimeout.

This method returns same value as unix shell return with "md5sum <file-name>"???

Comment: Looking into the implementation on jira ticket [HADOOP-3981](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3981) the checksum is calculated by running MD5 on the already-available CRC32 checksums of each "bytes.per.checksum" and then calculating an MD5 hash of the result. Adding this as an update to the answer above.

Comment: i have read all these jira tickets..and i am getting different MD5 value for local and hdfs file.....according to tickets it should be same...

Comment: According to the ticket, the distributed checksum is *not* a simple MD5 checksum on the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In this i have calculated the MD5 of both local and HDFS file and then compared the same for both files equality. Hope this helps.

```
public static void compareChecksumForLocalAndHdfsFile(String sourceHdfsFilePath, String sourceLocalFilepath, Map<String, String> hdfsConfigMap)
        throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", hdfsConfigMap.get(Constants.USERNAME));
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/tmp");
    Configuration hdfsConfig = new Configuration();
    hdfsConfig.set(Constants.USERNAME, hdfsConfigMap.get(Constants.USERNAME));
    hdfsConfig.set("fsURI", hdfsConfigMap.get("fsURI"));
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI(hdfsConfigMap.get("fsURI")), hdfsConfig);
    Path inputPath = new Path(hdfsConfigMap.get("fsURI") + "/" + sourceHdfsFilePath);
    InputStream is = hdfs.open(inputPath);
    String localChecksum = getMD5Checksum(new FileInputStream(sourceLocalFilepath));
    String hdfsChecksum = getMD5Checksum(is);
    if (null != hdfsChecksum || null != localChecksum) {
        System.out.println("HDFS Checksum : " + hdfsChecksum.toString() + "\t" + hdfsChecksum.length());
        System.out.println("Local Checksum : " + localChecksum.toString() + "\t" + localChecksum.length());

        if (hdfsChecksum.toString().equals(localChecksum.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Equal");
        } else {
            System.out.println("UnEqual");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Null");
        System.out.println("HDFS : " + hdfsChecksum);
        System.out.println("Local : " + localChecksum);
    }
}

public static byte[] createChecksum(String filename) throws Exception {
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    MessageDigest complete = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    int numRead;

    do {
        numRead = fis.read(buffer);
        if (numRead > 0) {
            complete.update(buffer, 0, numRead);
        }
    } while (numRead != -1);

    fis.close();
    return complete.digest();
}

// see this How-to for a faster way to convert
// a byte array to a HEX string
public static String getMD5Checksum(String filename) throws Exception {
    byte[] b = createChecksum(filename);
    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        result += Integer.toString((b[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**OutPut:**

```
HDFS Checksum : d99513cc4f1d9c51679a125702bd27b0    32
Local Checksum : d99513cc4f1d9c51679a125702bd27b0   32
Equal
```